# Is iLQG a good algorithm for model-based planning with simple environments?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, models

In their work *[Continuous Deep Q-Learning with Model-based Acceleration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00748)*, the author demonstrate great results of applying Imagination Rollouts for model-based acceleration of learning. They test their algorithm on manipulation tasks in a Mujoco simulation. 
I wonder whether similar accelaration would be possible in classic environments like `Pendulum-v0`.